# Oven Igniter Going Bad Quickly

Tags: electrical, oven

I have a hotpoint RGB535GET1AD gas oven. Around three years ago the igniter died and the landlord replaced it. Nine months ago it went bad again, and I replaced it myself. Yesterday the igniter went bad again. As I understand it an igniter should last longer than that. I have two questions:

1. Could I have done something while installing the igniter to make it go bad quickly?
2. Might there an underlying problem that would make the igniter die, and if so how would I diagnose it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a Viking stove with 2 ovens. The larger oven had 2 igniters and the smaller one had 1.   One igniter in the large oven had failed, but we didn't realize it. It just took a long time to heat up. Then the 2nd one failed, on Thanksgiving day, naturally!    I moved the igniter from the small oven to replace one of them in the large oven so at least we could get it partially working.

In doing research, I found that Viking igniters are notorious for failing.  I found a different brand replacement and it's been trouble free for at least 10 years.   You might see if you can find a higher quality replacement. Don't go for the cheapest, get the best.   I wish I could remember where I got the new ones to let you know, but it was 10 years ago and I forgot!